# For Each Groups of Registries do - Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, foreach

I'm with a trouble

Im using rails 3.2.8

i have an array with 90 positions called @tools.

I created a CSS style to print this list as a simple HTML report, so here starts the problem.
I got a div class called "page-break", but i want this div be inserted in the code for each 33 registers.

Is there a way to break the array in groups of 33 registers and in the end of this add the div page-break?

eg.

First block of 33

```
<table>
<thead>
#table header
</thead> 

<tbody>
# block of 33 registers coming from array
</tbody>

</table>

<div class="page-break">

Second block of 33

<table>
<thead>
#table header
</thead> 

<tbody>
# Second block of 33 registers coming from array
</tbody>

</table>
<div class="page-break">
```

etc until the end of registries on array.
Does someone knows an elegant way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each_slice` is a nice way to handle this. You could do something like:

```
<% @tools.each_slice(33) do |page| %>
   <table>
      <thead>
         #table header
      </thead> 
      <tbody>
         <% page.each do |tool| %>
         ...
         <% end %>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="page-break" />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Dan! Great! Thank You! Works very fine! But whats the diference from slice to in_groups_of?

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of `in_groups_of`. It looks like it's the same except that it allows you to insert nils to pad out the last group.

Comment: Good! i researched a lil about my problem while i was waiting some answer here. Anyway, your sugestion solved my issue! Thank you! ;)